# Jaxx ether wallet - loss of ether

Tags: myetherwallet

On or about May 23 I created  Jaxx V1.2 wallet on my iPhone and successfully made two deposits of ether. Several days ago I performed a "pair-restore" on a Jaxx wallet I had downloaded on my iMac. Thereafter my two ether deposits in my iPhone wallet disappeared. How do I recuperate my ether? In any response kindly bear in mind that my knowledge in this area is very limited.

I should perhaps add that the mnemonic belonging to my iPhone Jaxx wallet was identical to the one offered during my iMac pair-restore action.

Answer (score 4):

Search your address on etherscan.io. If the ETH are still there then you know they haven't moved at least. Then it is just a matter of getting access to your wallet via your private key (mnemonic phrase)

You can enter your 12 word phrase on MyEtherWallet.com to see if you have access to the funds at least. Go to the view or send tab, select mnemonic phrase, enter words, no password, click unlock, make sure the path that says Jaxx is selected, and your addresses will show below. Your balance should also show.

For debugging the Jaxx restore thing, their support is going to be the most helpful. Please though, when you find the solution, come back here and update your post with said solution. This helps future people.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I searched etherscan.io with my current address copied from Jaxx ion my iPhone . Unfortunately no ether left in the account. Does this mean that my ether is permanently lost? Interestingly Jaxx on my iMac shows only Bitcoin, Dash and LTC, but no Ethereum. Any significance? – Philipp 3 mins a

Comment: Does it show ETH coming into or out of that address?

Comment: My Jaxx iPhone wallet showed two incoming ETHS at their time of purchase. It does not/not show any outgoing ETHs.  But all ETHs appear to have left since the wallet is now bare. I did not do anything with the iPhone Jaxx wallet other than open it four or five times since installation in May.  I only did a pair/restore on the Jaxx wallet I installed on my iMac.

Comment: Many wallet clients do not show all transactions. Are you looking at the outgoing transactions on etherscan.io?

Answer (score 0):

1. https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction
2. mnemonic phrase 12 word
3. check Jaxx button/or other wallet
4. Check Address (ETH)
5. add SNTR If haven’t already made new token ticker
6. look it loaded your token. Complete.